# nginx - with only small cpu why nginx allocates so many workers

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

With `worker_processes auto;` and CPU req/limits is only 200m/375m why nginx is creating 50+ workers ?

Pod specs:

```
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: '512Mi'
              cpu: '200m'
            limits:
              memory: '768Mi'
              cpu: '375m'
```

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
```

```
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker processes
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 51
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 52
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 56
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 57
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 58
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 59
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 60
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 61
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 62
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 63
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 64
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 65
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 66
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 67
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 68
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 69
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 70
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 71
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 72
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 73
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 74
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 75
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 76
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 77
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 78
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 79
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 80
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 81
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 82
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 83
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 84
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 85
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 86
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 87
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 88
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 89
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 90
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 91
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 92
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 93
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 94
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 95
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 96
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 97
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 98
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 99
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 100
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 101
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 102
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 103
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 104
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 105
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 106
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 107
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 108
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 109
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 110
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 111
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 112
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 113
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 114
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 115
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 116
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start worker process 117
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start cache manager process 118
2024/02/15 12:17:15 [notice] 32#32: start cache loader process 119
```

Answer (score 0):

On the available [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#worker-processes), the [worker_processes number | auto;](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_processes) defines the number of worker processes which is an optimal value such as (but not limited to) the number of CPU cores, the number of hard disk drives that store data, and load pattern. You can set this on the configmap of nginx controller.

The number of `worker-process` also correlates on the `cpu.cfs\_quota\_us` which is part of [CFS Bandwidth Control](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.6/scheduler/sched-bwc.html) of the cluster.

You can read this [article](https://www.sobyte.net/post/2022-06/nginx-process-auto/) to understand more about the CFS/CPU usage of the nginx controller

Comment: This is not my question. Why 50 worker threads for only 200m CPU core/100GB  ?